# OutofMemory Exception for AES 256 bits Encryption (Bouncycastle) Android

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory

I am using Bouncycastle to do AES 256 bits encryption of file which will then be uploaded into the backend.

My app works perfectly on an Android 4.0 device. When I tested the same app on an Android 4.3 device, first it crashes showing OutofMemory exception while doing encryption. So I added in try catch exceptions.

It completed the encryption but the subsequent file sent to backend when decrypted file shows gibberish.

Not sure how this is possible since it is the same app with the same keys used.

Any idea how I can resolve this issue? Am I doing something wrong? Below is my encryption code:

```
public void encryptfile(String encpathname , String destencfile){

        try {

            byte enc[] = null;

            File file = new File(encpathname);
            byte[] data = new byte[(int) file.length()];

            FileInputStream fis;

                fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                fis.read(data);
                fis.close();

                enc = encrypt(passphrase, data);

                FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(destencfile);
                stream.write(enc);
                stream.close();

                file.delete();

                System.gc();

                }catch (Exception e) {

                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
    }

private static byte [] encrypt(String passphrase, byte [] inbytes) throws Exception {
                SecretKey key = generateKey(passphrase);

                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NOPADDING");
               // Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding", "BC");

                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, generateIV(cipher), random);
                return cipher.doFinal(inbytes);
            }

            private static SecretKey generateKey(String passphrase) throws Exception {
                PBEKeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(passphrase.toCharArray(), salt.getBytes(), iterations, keyLength);
                SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWITHSHA256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC");
                return keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);
            }

            private static IvParameterSpec generateIV(Cipher cipher) throws Exception {
                byte [] ivBytes = new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()];
                random.nextBytes(ivBytes);
                return new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);
            }
```

Comment: You cannot fix an error that caused an Exception by simply catching the Exception.

Comment: You probably should't try to load the entire file into memory either. Most of the encryption apis allow for streaming segments of data through a cipher, so you do cipher.init() and then for each segment of the file (read it in 1024 blocks or something), you call cipher.update(data), then on the last one you close it with cipher.final(). OTherwise you are going to send the entire thing in memory and depending on what the data is, many phones may not have the physical capacity to load the data

Comment: This will alos prevent, in cases where the file size is actually larger than Integer.MAX_VALUE bytes, from being only partially encrypted.